# Retry Request When Its Failed

Tags: python, web, request, urllib

I Programmed this code to get website content but there is a problem
when connection is filed the program stop and dont try to reconnect

```
            url= 'https://website.com'
            def get_page_content(url, head):
              """
              Function to get the page content
              """
              req = Request(url, headers=head)
              return urlopen(req)
            head = {
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36',
              'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
              'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
              'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
              'Connection': 'keep-alive',
              'refere': 'https://example.com',
              'cookie': """your cookie value ( you can get that from your web page) """
            }

            data = get_page_content(url, head).read()
```

I searched in the internet but didn't find solution.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include your attempt to solve the problem, as well as any error traceback message you're getting.

Comment: Put the code in a loop that uses `try/except` around the call to `urlopen()`. Break out of the loop when it succeeds.

Comment: Take a look at [tenacity](https://pypi.org/project/tenacity/). It provides some nice decorators for this type of thing. Especially useful for web retries is exponential backoff to avoid DOS-ing your servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has try, except blocks you can add. Basically you put the code that's failing (specifically the lines that throws errors) into the try section, and then the except portion will contain code that you want to do in the event of an error. You can use this with a flag in a loop to keep trying to connect a certain number of times

```
success_flag = False
while success_flag == False: # keep looping until success
     try: # code in here will attempt to run
          req = Request(url, headers=head)
          page = urlopen(req)
          success_flag = True # mark as successful run if got through the code that may fail
          return page
     except Exception as e: # this code will run in the event of a failure
          print(e) # just print the exception before trying again. 
          # possibly change something before reconnecting depending on error thrown
```

keep in mind you don't have the traceback posted, so there may be an issue with the code itself. This code will just do as you asked and that is keep trying again. You may need to change something before trying a reconnect

Answer (score 0):

You could use the status to retry when the requests fail.

`get_page_content(url, head)` has the property `status`. If the status is 200, 201, or 204 everything is ok. In any other case you should handle it.